# Can ibid. follow op. cit. instead of loc. cit. to convey "exactly as in the op. cit. above"?

Tags: citations

It would seem that the more familiar *ibid.* could be used instead of the more intricate *loc. cit.* in such a case.

For example if we have:

**11**. Stern, op. cit., p. 58.

and the subsequent citation is to also refer to Stern, p. 58 (precisely what *loc. cit.* is for), can it then be economically rendered as:

**12**. Ibid.

or should *loc. cit.* be used? It seems *ibid.* has generally supplanted *loc. cit.* for use in such instances.

Comment: "_Loc. cit._ (Latin, short for _loco citato,_ meaning "in the place cited") is a footnote or endnote term used to repeat the title and page number for a given work (and author). "_Loc. cit._ is used in place of _ibid_. when the reference is not only to the work immediately preceding, but also refers to the same page. _Loc. cit._ is also used instead of _op. cit._ when reference is made to a work previously cited and to the same page in that work. As such, _loc. cit._ is never followed by volume or page numbers." 

https://lispp.blogspot.com/2014/01/ibid-and-op-cit.html